# How to use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

What should be the workaround in this case? :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2005, `TEXT/NTEXT/IMAGE` are deprecated - you should use the `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` data types instead.

(N)VARCHAR(MAX) (see [MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)) and VARBINARY(MAX) allow up to 2 GByte of data

From the MSDN docs:

> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through
>   4,000. **max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.** (= 2 GB)

The (N)VARCHAR(MAX) types also allow all the usual T-SQL string function to work on them - something that wasn't the case with (N)TEXT at all.

As this [MSDN article shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx), the replacement types are supported in triggers, too:

> SQL Server 2008 does not allow for
>   **text, ntext, or image** column
>   references in the inserted and deleted
>   tables for AFTER triggers. However,
>   these data types are included for
>   backward compatibility purposes only.
>   The preferred storage for large data
>   is to use the **varchar(max)**,
>   **nvarchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** data
>   types. Both AFTER and INSTEAD OF
>   triggers **support varchar(max)**,
>   **nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max)** data
>   in the inserted and deleted tables.

Comment: hi marc, however, i hread that the NVARCHAR MAX is only 4000 character in unicode... im not sure about NTEXT. im working on 2008 and it seam working fine

Comment: Yes, NTEXT is still support in 2008 - not sure about 2008 R2 though. It's on its way out - replace it now. Using NVARCHAR(MAX), you can also use all the normal string functions on your field - you cannot do this on NTEXT in most cases.

Comment: http://sqltips.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/use-varcharmaxnvarcharmax-instead-of-text-ntext/ i found this one. Thank you marc

Answer (score 4):

This is the workaround:

[SQL Trigger cannot do INSTEAD OF DELETE but is required for ntext, image columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101924/sql-trigger-cannot-do-instead-of-delete-but-is-required-for-ntext-image-columns)

Essentially you need to join the `inserted` and/or `deleted` pseudo-tables onto the underlying table and read the `NTEXT`, `TEXT` or `IMAGE` data from the underlying tables.