# SQL Trigger cannot do INSTEAD OF DELETE but is required for ntext, image columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[C1_Deletions] ON [dbo].[C1] INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
  IF EXISTS ( SELECT 'True' FROM deleted JOIN C1 ON deleted.ACCOUNTNO = C1.ACCOUNTNO )
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [GDeletions].[dbo].[C1] SELECT * FROM deleted
    DELETE C1 FROM C1 INNER JOIN DELETED ON C1.ACCOUNTNO = DELETED.ACCOUNTNO
   END
```

So that is the trigger i'm trying to use, it works well when i'm deleting by accountno, but when i need to delete by recid(another column) i'm unable to.

If i change the INSTEAD OF to AFTER, i get errors about ntext, image columns not being allowed. Is there any way around this issue? I cannot be the one specifying the deletion string, the program itself does that i just need the trigger to grab the data that is being deleted.

The bigger problem i have is another table that stores history, it stored it with the accountno matching to the c1 table but then there is also recid which is unique to every entry. If i go to delete a C1 entry, it deletes all from history using accountno, but if i delete a single history entry then it deletes by recid.

Comment: If any answer was correct or helpful please accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, even if you delete multiple rows at once, each row is still put into the DELETED temporary table during the query execution, so my trigger then goes through each record and matches on recid(which is unique to each row) and deletes/moves from there.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access TEXT, NTEXT or IMAGE fields from INSERTED or DELETED. However you can access them from the base table by joining with INSERTED. This only works for INSERT and UPDATE because in a DELETE the base row no longer exists.

To achieve what you need, in another trigger, copy the primary key and TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE columns to a side table.

For example

```
create table C1(
   accountNo int identity primary key,
   someColumn nvarchar(10),
   someNtext ntext
)

create table C1_side(
   accountNo int primary key,
   someNtext ntext
)

create trigger trgC1_IU  on C1 AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
as
BEGIN
   -- Ensure side row exists
   insert C1_side(accountNo, someNtext)
   select accountNo from INSERTEd
   where not exists (select 1 from C1_side where C1_side.accountNo = inserted.accountNo)

   -- Copy NTEXT value to side row
   update C1_side
   set someNtext = c1.someNtext
   from C1_side inner join C1 on C1_side.accountNo = C1.accountNo
   inner join INSERTED on INSERTED.accountNo = C1.accountNo
   -- Could improve by checking if the column was updated for efficiency

END
```

Now, in your DELETE trigger, you can join DELETED to C1_side to read the previous value of the ntext column. Note that you will have to populate initial values for your side table, for rows which already exist in C1.

Answer (score 3):

Stop using ntext and image: [they are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Use nvarchar(max) and varbinary(max) instead. These act like normal datatypes, unlike the deprecated ones.

Comment: As easy as that would be, the software is closed source and uses image and ntext, it's just something i have to work with.

Comment: @iarp: well, why are you adding triggers then? Never mess with vendor code... you give them an excuse to stop supporting you.

Comment: while that may be, the triggers only purpose is to grab the data being deleted and place a copy in an identical database so that when someone comes to us in tech support because they made a bone head move, rather than spend hours restoring backups, we can simply go to the deletions database and export data.