# Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I tried casting ntext to nvarchar but I continue to get the `Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.`

```
CAST([Q Comments] As NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Is there a way to convert/cast to nvarchar to avoid that error?

Comment: One good way is not to use deprecated data types....

Comment: can you be more specific? Are you trying to use the tables on a trigger? I created an example where I could do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Trigger cannot do INSTEAD OF DELETE but is required for ntext, image columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101924/sql-trigger-cannot-do-instead-of-delete-but-is-required-for-ntext-image-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not.

`text`, `ntext` and `image` are not accessible in this form.

If you must, select the primary key from `inserted` and look up the value in the actual underlying table.

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't always help. For example, values in the `deleted` table are gone - you can't refer back to the base relation.

Comment: @Yuck They are, which is why I didn't say "`inserted` or `deleted`".