# scope_identity returns dbnull due to instead of trigger

Tags: sql

I have an instead of trigger on a table. The trigger is working fine but we have an application where users can perform bulk update to the table through UI. select scope_identity returns null in that case. I ran sql profiler to see what is going on in background when users perform update through UI and I got this:

```
insert into Table(column1, column2,....)
values (value1, value2,.....)
go
select scope_identity()
go
```

In this case, scope_identity() defined inside instead of trigger returns correct value but scope_identity() in the above statement returns null and the application throws error at this point. I guess this is because insert is happening inside trigger which does not come under the scope of above scope_identity.
I know this issue can be resolved by having after trigger in place of instead of trigger but the table contains ntext columns which would prevent me from using after trigger. Converting ntext columns to nvarchar(max) is also not an option for me.
Any ideas about how can I make the select scope_identity() return correct value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the contents of the trigger.

Comment: `select scope_identity()` should be in the same batch as insert - in other words, you need to remove `go`.

Comment: @Ben: I cannot post the trigger here but it goes something like this:                                                                  set ansi_nulls on  go  set quoted_identifier on  go  create trigger dbo.sampletrigger  on sampletable  insteadof insert  as  begin  //do some actions here  insert into sampletable(column1, column2,..) select column1, column2,... from inserted  select scope_identity()  end

Answer (score 0):

OK I can repro your problem and have an explanation and a solution.

```
use tempdb
go
set ansi_nulls on 
set quoted_identifier on 
go 
create table sampletable (
ix int identity primary key,
column1 nvarchar(50),
column2 nvarchar(50)
)
go
go
      /* First with no trigger - works fine */
insert sampletable(column1, column2)
select 'a', 'b'
select @@identity, scope_identity(), ident_current('sampletable')
select * from sampletable

go
      /* create instead trigger */
create trigger dbo.sampletrigger on sampletable 
instead of insert 
as 
begin 
insert into sampletable(column1, column2) select column1, column2 from inserted 
end
go

      /* Now scope_identity() is null */
insert sampletable(column1, column2)
select 'a', 'b'
select @@identity, scope_identity(), ident_current('sampletable')
select * from sampletable
go
go
go
drop table sampletable
```

`Scope_identity()` is null because you didn't insert a row with an identity in the current scope.

`Scope_identity()` is the last identity inserted in the current scope in the current batch. The trigger is a separate scope, so outside the trigger it is null.
You need to use `@@identity` which is the last identity inserted in the batch, regardless of scope.

You **cannot** use `ident_current('sampletable')` which is the last identity inserted in any batch and any session on that specific table, because that will potentially pick up changes due to other concurrent users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I know that if I use @@identity or ident_current('sampletable') it will return non-null value.
The problem here is that the below statements from my original question are auto generated by the application and I don't have access to background code. Hence, I cannot change scope_identity() to @@identity or ident_current('').
insert into Table(column1, column2,....)
values (value1, value2,.....)
go
select scope_identity()
go
Basically, I need a workaround such that the above scope_identity() returns non-null value. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @AnutoshDatta, you need to find a way to do it using an `AFTER` trigger then. Since you haven't told us yet what you are actually doing I cannot help any further.

Comment: This trigger creates change log entries for the table. The reason I am using instead of trigger is the table has ntext columns. I cannot change it to nvarchar(max) as it will impact other areas. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @AnutoshDatta, there is a way to solve that problem as I do exactly that. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101924/sql-trigger-cannot-do-instead-of-delete-but-is-required-for-ntext-image-columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the plan is I will change instead of trigger to after trigger. Will let you know how this works out. Thanks again.

Comment: What are the impacts of converting ntext column to nvarchar(max)?

Comment: @AnutoshDatta, if you read my answer you can see that there is no need to convert the column type. By joining `inserted` and `deleted` tables onto the base table you can access the `ntext` data in the base table.

Comment: I have already implemented your suggestion and it really resolves my issue here. But I would also like to know if there are any bad impacts if I convert ntext to nvarchar(max). Seems like ntext is depreciated and will likely be removed from future versions of sqlserver. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot advise. I suggest that unless you use `READTEXT` or `WRITETEXT` you will probably be OK, but the best way is to test it in a test environment.

Comment: @Ben I can't find anywhere online that indicates that ident_current is batch specific, it seems to just return the most recent id created on a given table.  Saying that it is batch specific seems to imply scope.  In most scenarios it is probably reasonable to assume that these are the same, but under enough load -- wouldn't the most recent ID and the ID created withing a given script not be guaranteed to be the same?